# XNA AI: Managing Enemies on Screen

Tags: c#, design-patterns, xna

I have two classes, Human and Monster.

both have a Property called MoveBehavior

Human has HumanMoveBehavior, and Monster has MonsterMoveBehavior

I want the HumanMoveBehavior to move AWAY from Monsters, and MonsterMoveBehavior to move TOWARD Humans.

The problem I'm having is where should I put my code to move?

In the Human/Monster class?

Using this approach, I had a Move() Method, which takes a List of all entities in game, decides whether it's a Monster or Human using a method called GetListOfOpponents(List allsprites) and then runs GetNearestOpponent(List opponents);

But this looks really messy.

Should I have a SpriteController that decides where the Sprites move? I'm unsure where I need to put this code :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could think of a `AIManager` that just says:

```
foreach(GameObject go in m_myObjects) // m_myObjects is a list of all objects that require updating
{
    go.Update(); // standard GameObject function
}
```

After that, each class should take care of its own piece of code. So updating works in the class itself.

So Human says:

```
// just a class which is a gameObject and also has moving behaviour
// do the same with monster
public class Human : GameObject, IMoveBehaviour
{
    public override Update()
    {
        GoMove();
    }

    public void GoMove()
    {
        // human specific logic here
    }
}

// This interface describes that some movement 
// will happen with the implementing class
public interface IMoveBehaviour
{
    void GoMove();
}
```

With using an interface, you can make the specific language part of the class and you don't have need to ALSO create some class that will handle that for you. Of course it is possible. But in real life, the human/monster is the one that is moving, not some object he is carrying.

*UPDATE*

Answer to the comment. Because there is an `AIManager`, or even a complete `GameObjectManager` would be nice to maintain all `GameObjects`, you could ask the `AIManager` for the placed where you could not go.

Because pathfinding is most of the time done by use of some navigation mesh or a specified grid, the `GameObjectManager` can return the specific Grid with all navigable points on it. You should for certain not define all positions in every monster. Because most of the time, the monster does not exactly know where everyone is (in real life). So knowing where not to go is indeed good, but knowing where everyone is, will give your AI too much advantage as well.

So think of returning a grid with the points where to go and where not to, instead of maintaining such things inside the monster/human. Always check where you should leave what, by thinking about what would be the thing in real life.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice, the thing I'm not sure about is that the Human and Monster class need to know the locations of all other players on the level, so that they can decide where to move, how would you handle this?

Comment: As you know that a `Human` and a `Monster` both have positions, health and a few other common types, I would create a base interface with these common types in and inherit so you'd have: `public class Human : IEntity`.

Comment: @Ardman: Indeed a good suggestion, but I shouldn't make it an interface, because you want a variable to be in your IEntity. A base-class would maybe be a better suggestion.

Comment: @Marnix: I've just noticed you used `GameObject`.  Nice :o)

Comment: @Ardman: Still it is a good idea of you to use another base-class in between, like `Entity`, but not `IEntity` as an interface, because you want to add variables like `health` and `walkingSpeed`.

Comment: @Marnix:  That's what I'd do.  Or, at least thats what I've done here: http://project-vanquish.co.cc/

Comment: @Ardman: So because you use `IEntity`, you always have to specify things like `walkingSpeed` right? So still, why do you use an interface instead of an interlaying class like `Entity` instead of the interface `IEntity`?

Comment: @Marnix: Sorry, I meant that I use this type of inheritance in my project.  I have an `Entity` class which is, I guess, similar to your `GameObject` class.

Comment: @Ardman: Good to know =) `GameObject` was (two years ago when I used XNA) the main object to place and draw in the game. I think it still is? It only has an `Update` and `Draw` function. Does it still exist?

Comment: Hi guys, I'm using an abstract class called Sprite with base properties that they all share (texture, etc) then I'm adding human and monster classes which implement a MovingBehavior interface which can either be MonsterBehavior or HumanBehavior. I WAS going to pass my entire List<Sprite> into my xBehavior.Move method but that seems ugly...

Comment: @toleero: That *is* ugly, because then your `xBehavior.Move` will have to do all the calculations of the grid *again*, but your manager can also do this once per frame. I still don't know why you need the MonsterBehavior class/interface. There is already a MovingBehavior interface that can be implemented right?

Comment: MovingBehavior is used to create MonsterBehavior and HumanBehavior, basically each instance of Monster and Human has a Behavior reference variable that points to Monster or Human, so then I call Human.Behavior.Move() or Monster.Behavior.Move(), is that right?

Comment: @toleero: Sure you could do that. If your Monster class is really that big that it shouldn't be in there and is really a seperate object, then you should implement it like that =) Not everything needs a specific class I believe, but that's up to you of course.

Comment: Ok, I'm looking at your answer now and it makes sense, I'm not sure how to generate a grid showing where my players can go and where they can't though, I want humans to move away from monsters, and monsters towards humans, do you have any links that show how to create basic AI?

Comment: @toleero: You are going towards a pathfinding problem, because obviously, your world isn't empty. Try finding an [A* algorithm](http://www.policyalmanac.org/games/aStarTutorial.htm). To produce the grid you are walking in, you just have to fill in some sort of table. This table can be used by your `A*`. Walking away and towards is then just a case of setting your goal point in the grid.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I have a much better idea of what I need to do thanks to you. Could my 'Grid' be a 2D array of pixels in the game world? The problem is that if there's no Monster around, my Human has no 'path', his sole purpose is to avoid the Monster, I think this may be a design issue :) 

So I'm going to create your AIManager, I'm also thinking of creating a GraphicsHelper which has a Clamp() function to lock movement to screen borders, along with being able to return viewport info, etc, is this a good idea? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @toleero Seems fine to me. You can always adjust the detail of the grid by saying: `1 cell = 4px` or even more. One more thing you should care for, is the radius of your monsters, because they are not 1px big. So, when calculating if you may walk there, keep the size of your monsters in mind. (Could you accept my answer if you're done?)

Comment: Yep sure, I was just about to infact. At the moment my Monsters are 32px*32px, thanks for all of your advice :)

Answer (score 0):

The way Valve handled this for entities in Half Life 2, is one of the better ways, I think. Instead of giving each AI its own separate Move methods and calling those, it simply called the Think() method and let the entity decide what it needed to do.

I'd go with what Marnix says and implement an AIManager that loops through each active AI in the game world, calling the Think() method of each. I would not recommended interfacing your Human class with an "IMoveBehavior" simply because it would be better to abstract that into a "WorldEntity" abstract class.

You might have invisible entities that control things like autosaves, triggers, lighting, etc, but some will have a position in the world. These are the ones who will have a vector identifying their position. Have the AI's Think() method call its own move() method, but keep it private. The only one who needs to think about moving is the AI itself.

If you want to encourage the AI to move outside of the Think) method, I would suggest some kind of imperative, such as a Goal-Oriented Action Planning (GOAP) system. Jeff Orkin wrote about this fantastic concept, and it was used in games such as F.E.A.R. and Fallout 3. It might be a bit overkill for your application, but I thought it was interesting.

http://web.media.mit.edu/~jorkin/goap.html